# Clojure java-interop chained calls

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm having trouble rewriting to java-interop these chained calls:

```
 String logoutUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8180/auth")
   .path(ServiceUrlConstants.TOKEN_SERVICE_LOGOUT_PATH)
   .queryParam("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/product-portal")
   .build("Realm")
   .toString();
```

to clj:

```
logoutUrl (-> (UriBuilder/fromUri "http://localhost:8180/auth")
              (.path ServiceUrlConstants/TOKEN_SERVICE_LOGOUT_PATH)
              (.queryParam "redirect_uri" "http://localhost:8080/product-portal")
              (.build "Realm")
              (.toString))
```

I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;` (on line 2).

Comment: There is no call to `.path` method in your Java code. Is your question correct?

Comment: yes - I've got the answer on a slack channel though - build and queryParam take vararags, so they need to be in a vector as in: (.build (into-array Object ["Realm"]))

Comment: The call to `path` was there, just got lost in the formatting. Would good to see a real answer to this good question.

Comment: One of these functions (My guess is `queryParam`) is taking a variable number of arguments. These need to be put into an array `(into-array Object ["redirect_uri" "http://.."])`. If this fixed it I can answer...

Comment: @ClojureMostly - this is indeed the solution (see my comment above).